# wordpress .html / .css remove space between <img> and <div>

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```
<div class="main-navigation">

....

</div>

<img src="" width="961" height="10px" alt="greyLine">
```

Hi my problem is that after a `div` element i want to insert a `img` and as you can see ( in the google chrome browser developer tools screenshot )

[image]

[image]

there is a *space* between the red horizontal menu and the grey line.

[image]

I have no clue how to eliminate this space. I cannot find any 
padding, Border or margin between the  `<div class="main-navigation"></div>` and the `<img>` tag and to my restircted .css knowledge then there should be no space

Comment: It looks like you have a `<ul>` list inside your `<div class="main-navigation">`, is there any padding on that or the `<li>` elements? Also look for a `line-height` value.  This question would likely be very hard to definitively answer unless you can find a way to get the full markup of just this issue in the question (or possibly on a service like CSSdesk.com)

Comment: Here is what your example HTML and implied CSS looks like in cssdesk: http://www.cssdesk.com/EQgRB

Comment: Have you tried doing a `clear: both;` on the last element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could provide a url I can give a exact answer. But..... here are some options

1. remove the img tag and add a div with css background gradient colors as in image
2. make img "position:absolute" and adjust the position with "top" or "margin-top"
3. try adding margin:0, padding:0 to img tag(not sure)